# WatchKit setBackground Color Crash

Tags: swift, crash, watchkit, uicolor

After importing UIKit and attempting to toggle around with where to initialize the buttons colors programmatically, I can't seem to figure out why a crash occurs in the class conforming to WKInterfaceController

```
import UIKit
import WatchKit

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

  @IBOutlet fileprivate var myButton : WKInterfaceButton!

  override func willActivate() { // About to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()

    self.myButton.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.red) // CRASH
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your current row of code, show the error message.

Comment: @RashwanL just attached image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason was in unused breakpoints.**

Anyway:

Use `awake(withContext:)` for changing UI:

> When creating an interface controller, WatchKit instantiates the class
>   and calls its  init() method followed shortly by its 
>   awake(withContext:)  method. Use those methods to initialize
>   variables, load data, and configure the items in your storyboard
>   scene. If WatchKit passes a valid object to the awake(withContext:)
>   method, use the information in that object to customize the
>   initialization process.

You can't use `willActivate()` for changing background color etc.:

> The  willActivate()  method lets you know when your interface is
>   active. Use the willActivate() method to perform any last minute
>   tasks, such as checking for updates to your content. (Do not use it
>   for your primarily initialization.)

Also always use `weak` outlets:

```
  @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var myButton : WKInterfaceButton!
```

And check that your outlet was connected.

Comment: the button is not returning nil so im not sure what the  problem is , and regarding `weak`. In iOS I know that when connecting outlets that `weak` is used by default, but not in WatchOS - so I didn't want to add something that apple figured shouldn't be there.

Comment: Other than the guard statement returning a print statement I'm not sure how to add other error catching type of text. What do you mean by error message text, could you possibly provide an example?

Comment: @lifewithelliott There're should be error message in console log (at the bottom right of the Xcode window). Something like `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: nope. that's why im so confused why such a simple task is resulting in a crash. switched all my outlets to weak, Not sure why they weren't automatically weak since apple docs show that you were right. I added an additional image of the properties in the debug console

Comment: Outlets are connected, outlets have been switched to weak, setBackground color being called when I would think its acceptable. But still a mysterious crash to me

Comment: @lifewithelliott updated answer. Just don't use willActivate method :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147656/discussion-between-vasilii-muravev-and-lifewithelliott).

Comment: I genuinely appreciate the hard work in helping, but I've already tried awakeWithContext ( see third just attached image ). Im about to flip the laptop over to another dimension lol.